# Using Bootstrap's Datepicker with ControllerAs syntax

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

When I try to use Bootstrap's Datepicker within an Angular controller that uses the `controllerAs` syntax, the following code does not work:

```
$("#endDatePicker").datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YY'}).on('dp.change', function (e) {
    alert(1);
    vm.project.endDateFormatted = e.date.format('DD/MM/YY');
    vm.project.endDate = e.date.unix();
});
```

The test alert never happens and the datepicker simply dos not work in my view, so the following markup does nothing:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="startDatePicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDatePicker" ng-model="vm.startDateFormatted" placeholder="Project Start Date" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

However, if I do exactly the same in a controller that uses the standard `$scope` syntax, the datepicker works normally.

Upon further investigation I found out that selecting #startDatePicker within the controller's `activate()` yields the following result:

[image]

My controller can't seem to find the element with that `id` and this is somehow tied to the fact that I'm using the `controllerAs` syntax.

How can I fix this issue without switching to a `$scope` syntax?

Comment: It will not work as expected, because of the way you use jQuery with Angular.

Comment: But why does it work with $scope? Is switching to the $scope syntax within this controller the only chance I have?

Comment: It will not work with scope well too. You should not rely on DOM in controller. Directives are the way to do it properly.